# KeyError: "['Close'] not found in axis"

Tags: python, pandas

I am making an algorithm with ML in Python but I came across this error.

**KeyError: "['Close'] not found in axis"**

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve

plt.style.use("seaborn")
%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data.head()

X = data.drop(columns="Close", axis=1)
y = data["Close"].values
```

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your `data`  but my guess it does not have a column named `Close`. Or there is some whitespace around it, use `print(data.columns)` to check. In general please follow these rules: [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples),  [mcve]

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that there was an extra space in front of each column for some reason.